# Planes containing a given curve

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, euclidean-geometry, differential-topology, curves

Excuse the naive question. I am trying to build a geometric intuition which I always lacked.

I can see that if I have a line in $\mathbb{R}^3,$ then I have a plane where the line is entirely contained.

Actually, I have a sheaf of infinitely many planes containing a given line, because I can rotate in 3D space any given plane where the axis of rotation is the given line, obtain all the other planes containing it.

On the other hand, a plane not parallel and not containing entirely the line but intersecting it will meet the line at exactly one point.

So far so good?

Ok, then what about a generic curve?

For example, I can take $S^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^3.$

Then a generic plane not parallel to this $S^1$ will meet the circle in exactly two points.

On the other hand, there exists for sure a plane where this $S^1$ entirely lies on. Is this plane unique in this case? I think yes.

Is it always unique for any curve different than a line? I think yes also.

Does it have to do with the fact that the line has zero curvature?

Comment: It has to do with **torsion**. Zero torsion implies that the curve lies in a plane.

Comment: e.g. an helix is not contained in a plane

Comment: @GCab Maybe the question is not clear, but I am not asking about the existence of a plane, but on the uniqueness.

Comment: @Somos see the above comment.

Comment: Anyways thank you both for your comment

Comment: If there are three non-collinear points on the curve, then any plane containing the curve must be the unique plane containing those $3$ points.  So, a planar curve that is not a line lies on a unique plane.

Comment: @saulspatz What is the definition of non-collinear? means 3 points not lying on a straight line?

Comment: @ggeolier Yes, that's it.